# protected method `new' called for Braintree::Address:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, payment, braintree

i recently installed Braintree payment gem. It conflicted with my Address model since Braintree has their own Address model too, so i moved my Address model inside my own module.

```
module MyModule
   class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   end
end
```

However every time I use Address, i have to prefix MyModule::Address otherwise it uses Braintree::Address by default if i don't use the MyModule prefix.

how i do tell rails to use MyModule::Address by default?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do this by default but I have always gotten around it by either namming my class, AAddress or by forking the gem and changing their code to better suit me. Then in your gemfile, you can point to your own gem that you forked.

Comment: You could also wrap your classes with another object called "TrueAddress" and have it take a type. If no type was specified, you can default to your address model. Could also use a namespace on your but then you have to prefix it.

Comment: there is something fundamentally wrong here....`Braintree::Address` should not be accessible as `Address`..in what context do you call this class?

Comment: @tihom i'm just doing address = Address.new and received this error 'protected method `new' called for Braintree::Address:Class'

Comment: when I install the gem and try to access `Address.new` it gives me the error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Address`. If I do `Braintree::Address.new` then it throws the protected error. So there is something else going on here. You need to provide some more context..

Comment: i added this to the routes in order to use address resources.  scope 'mymodule' do
    resources :addresses, as: 'mymodule_addresses'
  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alias `Address` to your own class.

```
 Address = MyModule::Address
```

If you're inside the Braintree module, you can access your class using the `::` syntax like so:

```
::Address
```